# No internet until disable/enable ethernet (Win 10, 20H2)

Tags: windows-10, networking

I started experiencing internet issue after upgrading to 20H2. The symptom is:

- After logon to desktop, internet is very unstable. Most of the time, DNS failed to resolve and ping returns `General Failure`.
- Disable and reenable Ethernet completely fixes the issue.
- The *logon screen* seems to have internet, as the background image changes from time to time; The *lock screen* does not.

I changed the IPv4 precedence as Microsoft [suggested](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows). Also tried uninstalling the device then rebooting. None helped.

I've removed all features like Hyper-V, container, WSL, etc. There are only Bluetooth (PAN), Realtek Ethernet, and a few WAN Miniport interfaces.

There is a similar [issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-remove-vethernet-ethernet-hyper-v-virtual/b4c6d402-39cc-45f6-8fac-db877c4e9239?page=1) but the proposed fix unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Update BIOS, Power and Network Drivers. Restart and run TCP/IP Reset, restart again and test.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: It went too far by suggesting BIOS update.

Comment: Did you try the Reset and the other drivers?

Comment: @anch2150 - What do you mean "it went too far by suggesting BIOS update"?

Comment: Try to repair Internet connection using Windows network diagnostics. If the tool was unable to fix the problem, see the exact error message that were detected.

Comment: @John it doesn't work

Comment: @Ramhound It's no difference to "restart your computer". I'm also interested in knowing the root cause, even more than a blind fix.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest driver installed for the Ethernet chip. The driver provided on the manufacturer's web site is often better and more stable than the one retrieved via WindowsUpdate.

Comment: @anch2150 - Sometimes "restarting" an operating system is a real solution to a problem.  There are often times strange behavior can be exhibited due to a pending update.  This strange behavior is due to that pending update and is resolved, by the pending update being applied.  So have you updated your BIOS firmware?

Comment: @anch2150 - I posted a solution for you to consider.  No harm whatsoever in trying a Keep All to see.

Comment: Eventually disable/reenable Hyper-V and Application Guard solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I've removed all features like Hyper-V, container, WSL, etc. There are
> only Bluetooth (PAN), Realtek Ethernet, and a few WAN Miniport
> interfaces.  ...  I'm also interested in knowing the root cause, even
> more than a blind fix.

You have made a number of changes (I do not have remove WAN Miniport drivers for example) that make it very difficult to determine what the error is.

Suggestions made to date have not worked.  Trying to determine the root causes is now akin to finding a needle in a haystack.

Accordingly, the next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install. There are three levels in the steps below:  Keep Everything - best if it works;  Keep Data only; and Keep Nothing - is very close to a fresh install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

Comment: Appreciate you reply. Eventually disable/reenable Hyper-V and Application Guard solved the issue.

Comment: Interesting update because Hyper-V (running here) does not upset or impede Internet in any way.

Comment: I can only speculate: the routing table was messed up during the upgrade.